# popToRootViewControllerAnimated is not updating UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data, reloaddata

I'm working on small CoreData program with one UITableView with embedded Navigation controller and UIViewController, where to add the CoreData.

[image]

The problem is that I can't figure out how to reload the data in the table after press the save button.

I have tried to use popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) in the @IBAction func buttonSavePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem), but this just send me to the TableView without reloading the data.

```
    @IBAction func buttonSavePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) { 

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

}

I have also tried self.navigationController?.showViewController(contractsView, sender: storyboard) but this create another view in the stack, not the original, if I can explained like this.

```
    @IBAction func buttonSavePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   let contractsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContractsTableViewControllerStoryboardID") as ContractsTableViewController

    self.navigationController?.showViewController(contractsView, sender: storyboard)
```

}

I am new with the programming, which means that I can not aways ask the right questions. So I am posting the code, which is in working stage without comments - sorry

//  ContractsTableViewController.swift

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ContractsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
//, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

var totalContracts = 0

@IBOutlet var tableContracts: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contract")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    totalContracts = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
    println(totalContracts)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return totalContracts
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")

    var appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contract")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    var thisContract = results[indexPath.row] as Contract

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "From" + " " + thisContract.stratdate + " " + "to" + " " + thisContract.enddate
    cell.textLabel!.text = thisContract.workingdays + " " + "days" + " " + "as" + " " + thisContract.position + " " + "on" + " " + thisContract.ship

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")

    var appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contract")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    context.deleteObject(results[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
    context.save(nil)
    totalContracts = totalContracts - 1
    tableContracts.reloadData()

}
```

}

Comment: If your table view is in the root view controller where you are poping to, in that class in viewWillAppear() method call self.tableView.reloadData().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your tableView controller loads back `viewDidAppear` function will called. so you can reload tableView into that function like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You can navigate to RootView this way:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

This is working fine.

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/CoreData) is your working project.

Comment: Is not allow me to use it with class ContractsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: Thank you for that. But again the viewDidAppear is not a member of the class. Is it way to use it in this case?

Comment: Is still not working. Seems like the view is loaded in the memory and is not executing any code.

Comment: It should work!! can you give me sample project that I can test?

Comment: Seems that is time to update it :) I was waiting for better signal, because I am at sea right now ;)

Comment: I was trying to increase the rating but is not working, because my reputation is less than 15 yet. Not sure how to accept the answer

Comment: Happpy  to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take the IBOutlet of UITableView in ContractsViewController. Then put the reload the tableview using the below code:

```
self.myTableView.reloadData()
```